# Is there a way to use Mobius transformation to prove existence of Laurent Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I'd like to prove the existence of a Laurent series for a function with a pole. The kind of proof I have in mind must use an inversion. The key idea is that if
$$f\left(z\right)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^{n},$$
inside a circle $C_1$ then it must be
$$f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{n},$$
outside a circle $C_2$. The idea it seems clear but I can't fill in the details... is there some fault in the reasoning?

Comment: If $f(z) = \sum_n a_n z^n$ for $|z| \in (r,R)$ then $f(1/z) = \sum_n a_n z^{-n}$ for $|z|\in (R^{-1},r^{-1})$

Comment: Expanding on @reuns comment above, the action of $1/z$ on a unit disk centered at the origin is to flip the interior and exterior of a disk (while also flipping the disk horizontally... You need a negative sign to fix that). As such, if $f(z)$ converges for $|z| \le 1$ then $f(1/z)$ will converge for $|z| \ge 1$. This can be proven via the theory of Mobius Transforms rather quickly. Then, either by extending this to a circle of general radius or by changing variables twice, we get the result reuns gives.